# In RxCocoa/RxSwift, how to observe BehaviorRelay<[object]> array size changed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'd like to subscribe to a BehaviorRelay<[object]>, and I'd like to execute some functions whenever we append or remove elements.

I've used the distinctUntilChange method

```
BehaviorRelay<[object]>.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged{ $0.count != $1.count}.subscribe{....}
```

But didn't work. What should I try?  Should I try using other Subjects or Relays to achieve this purpose?

```
var objects = BehaviorRelay<[Object]>(value: [])
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

objects.asObservable()
.subscribe(onNext: { (objects) in
//Do something only when appending or removing elements.
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)

//For example
let tempObj = objects.value

tempObj.append(newObj)
objects.accept(tempObj)//this will be called

tempObj.removeAll()
objects.accept(tempObj)//this will be called

tempObj.property = "Change Property"
objects.accept(tempObj)//this will NOT be called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation:

> - parameter comparer: Equality comparer for computed key values.

I believe you should check the Equality with `==` operator. So, in your case, try this way:

```
BehaviorRelay<[object]>
    .asObservable()
    .distinctUntilChanged{ $0.count == $1.count}
    .subscribe{....}
```